# Do I really need css clear for a 2 column layout with header and footer?

Tags: css, css-float

I have read tutorial here http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/ and it says :

to resolve footer issue I would need to use css clear on footer :

```
#footer {
  clear: both;
}
```

I tried without css clear and just used css float:right for footer, I tested on multiple browsers including mobile and it seems to be OK, so what's wrong with not using css clear for a 2 column layout ? Are there circumstances when the layout would wreck with my css style (within an iframe or whatsoever) ?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        2 column layout
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">

        #header {
            background-color: yellow;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #footer {
            background-color: orange;
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div.left {
            float: left;    
        }
        div.right {
            float: right;
        }

        .column {
            width: 50%;
        }       

        img {
          float: right;
          margin: 0 0 1em 1em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id='header'>
    header
</div>

<div class='left column'>
    <img src="css-float.png">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

<div class='right column'>
    <img src="css-float.png">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit.
</div>

<div id='footer'>
    footer
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't see an issue as your footer is set to `float: left; width: 100%`, so with the flow of the content, you will see it appear under the other elements in the page. The combination of the float and width means the footer will only display where it can use 100% width, which in your case is under the other content.

If you take the `float: left` off, you will see it ruin your layout:

### [JS Fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/pFZcd/1/)

If you then add the `clear: both;` style, you will see that the [clear fix hack](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/), will clear the previous floats and the flow of the page will be restored:

### [JS Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/pFZcd/2/)

An alternative is to use a fixed 'sticky' footer, that is pinned to the bottom of the page and you can do away with both of the above hacks:

### [JS Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/pFZcd/3/)

Comment: yes but still don't understand why would I prefer clear:both solution over adding float: left solution ? clear seems more a hack than float:left which feels just natural ?

Comment: floating your footer that has 100% width is a hack that simply allows it to follow the page flow by not overlapping other content, you'd usually float an element when you want content to wrap around it. Personally, I think the clear: both method is more natural than telling an element to float, when it isn't being used to wrap other content.

Comment: have posted an alternative method